# How razorpay Add On works? Can we add them once in a subscription and it will work without updating in future?

Tags: payment-gateway, add-on, razorpay

I want to add a dynamic subscription amount for customers in Razorpay. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razorpay Subscription Add-ons are charged for a single billing cycle only. They are not recurring in nature and will not be automatically added to any future invoices.please refer - https://razorpay.com/docs/subscriptions/dashboard/add-ons/

Dynamic subscriptions can be catered in 2 ways using Razorpay subscription.

1. Using subscription with Addon

   - You can charge your customer one a month (Fixed + addon)
     Sample use case -
     Acme Corp. is a merchant who provides DTH services. A customer asks that Acme Corp. add the sports channel pack, which costs an additional ₹300, to his subscription only for the next month. Before the next billing cycle, Acme Corp. can add ₹300 to the customer's current bill amount as an add-on.

for details refer - https://razorpay.com/subscriptions/

2. Using charge at will (E-mandate or Paper Nach)

   - You can charge your customer anytime (Amount limitations as per the mandate)

   Sample use case -
   As an online marketing agency, you would offer various plans to your clients to run their advertisement campaigns on different platforms.
   For example, a customer might want to run their advertisement campaign on various online platforms for the next three months and will pay you ₹1,000 per 5,000 clicks over the next three months.
   In this case, you would want to authorize the selected payment method so you can charge them for every 5,000 clicks. You can do this by using Emandate / paper Nach.

for details refer - https://razorpay.com/e-mandate/